# How do I treat crumbling lath and plaster in my bathroom?

Tags: repair, lath-and-plaster

I have lath and plaster in my bathroom. The west wall in the bathroom keeps crumbling into a powdery substance.  My dad has fixed it a number of times but it keeps reappearing.  The powdery area is all around the window and up on the ceiling.  I don't see any water or feel any moisture on the wall.

How do I stop this pattern?

Comment: was it ever painted or is it bare plaster/spackle from previous repairs?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend replacing all or part of the wall with drywall. Specifically, greenboard. If you patch only part of the wall you may need to use furring strips or use a thicker greenboard to make it flush.

As a bonus, if you rip apart part of the wall you may find there is something else hidden back there that is causing this issue which you can address at that time.

Comment: Greenboard is OK, but I'd suggest going with one of the newer paperless boards (such as DensArmor--which uses a fiberglass surface))